# How do you customize the login-fields in php to make a site similar to Facebook or other popular login sites?

Tags: php

For example, with the login I made with a php script, the login boxes (username and password) are blocky (I've seen rounded corners login-forms) and the spacings are uneven (one is above the other).

Is there anyway to customize how login-boxes are designed and aligned in php, similar to how css is used at times (I'm not as familiar with css) or within php?

http://img845.imageshack.us/i/facebooklogin.jpg vs. http://img577.imageshack.us/i/loginq.jpg/

Answer (score 0):

CSS is the way to style this. If you aren't comfortable doing it, try to find some CSS stylesheets that already exist to style forms.

Alternatively, you can use javascript plugins like jQuery's [uniform](https://github.com/pixelmatrix/uniform) and call it on your inputs to style them automagically.

Answer (score 0):

Styling of any html form fields, regardless of how they're processed, should be done with CSS. It's not hard - there's a great tutorial/reference at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp).

In response to your specific question (rounded corners), you'd use the border-radius property:

```
    <style> 
    .rounded  {
        border: 1px solid black;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    }
    </style> 

    <input type="text" class="rounded" name="username" />
```